# Using a reference variable in HTML for connection

Tags: html, sql, reference

Can we use a reference variable in simple html? If yes, then how can we use reference variable to reach our connection string already defined in a separate connection class?

Comment: HTML has absolutely zero concept of "variables", and even less of SQL or "connection strings".

Answer (score 0):

No, Its not possible with HTML.